# Should i have shoved with QQ?

Tags: tournament

Tournament, 16 players left, about 50 have exited, blinds are 250-500,  I have 15K, the BB had 30K, it folds to me in dealer position, I shove QQ, SB folds, BB calls and wins with AA. I would have needed to be at least 8 to be in the money, and the play was quite loose at this point.

I think this is bad? at the bubble, loose play, and i have a big stack, so i should be cautious??

Comment: There are some good answers here already, but just want to comment, I personally think small ball poker is a good style in these late stages before the bubble. Your chips are valuable and often small bets can achieve the same thing as large bets, as they represent such a large amount of everyone's stack. Although let's be real here, this is just a bad beat, it's very rarely a mistake to shove QQ pre late game, of course there are better options to take, you're missing value. Is raising 3BB a better line? Yep I'd say so, but they're folding anything that's not top % hand unless they're loose.

Answer (score 5):

No, that was a massive overbet, given your stack size. A standard sized bet of about 3BB would have been better.

Although, in hindsight, it's possible you may have gotten into a raising war, and ended up all in anyway, depending on your read of the villain.

Answer (score 1):

You were down to 20 orbits so on the edge of being a big stack.

I am OK with shoving QQ here. You want to fold out any weak ace or suited king.

Problem is you are only going to get called by better hands so you are putting a lot at risk to win the blinds.  JJ or AKs might call but I doubt it.

You are not really deep enough to be set mining.  But it is close.

A flop is going to see an ace or king about 40%.

A standard 3 BB raise is probably a better line.  When you get raised you kind of need to 3 bet if play had been loose so it is going in anyway.  If you just get called you are ahead and in position.

Answer (score 1):

I think shoving from the button is okay with ~20BB with certain hands. 30BB is too much to shove. Shoving monster hands like queens is a big mistake, because you lose a lot of value. Shoving much worse hands would be a big mistake, because you risk too much, for too little.

When you open, the big blind is shoving / 3-betting 55+, AT+, KQ for sure, whereas he should fold some of these hands to your shove. He can still 3-bet bluff you with a weak suited ace or a weak suited connector. You can stack many hands where they hit top pair on boards that are Q high or lower. Shoving QQ allows your opponent to not make any mistakes and you will lose a lot of value.

With 15 left and top 8 pay, it is not really the bubble yet. Only 50% cashes. Don't worry about cashing too much, it is much more important to build up a stack, so you can be a big stack on the real bubble and moving forward after that.

You can't ever have avoided busting with 30BB on the button with queens. In this exact hand, your actions didn't really matter. In other situations, open instead of shove!

Answer (score 0):

It's not "bad", which doesn't mean a smaller bet wasn't worse. But it's not like you were better off not risking anything. You only get destroyed by AA and KK which they'll get about 1 in 60 hands, so if you get 2BB for a fold 59 out of 60 times, you are definitely positive, even accounting for the fact that you are somewhat near the money so losing 30BB at once hurts more than winning 2BB 15 times. Against JJ, TT, AQ, you own them bad, and against AK you win by 55% which might be not ideal.